# Using Jsoup in Android to get data from select element

Tags: android, jsoup, html-select

I want to make an app that downloads data from a website. I was going to use Jsoup but I can't figure out how to use it for the  element.
Here is a fragment of the site.

```
    <select size="4" name="lb_select" id="lbSelect">
<option value="b5708c52-42b3-4587-b886-61be9ac6915a">aaaa</option>
<option value="356a9389-0f88-4e70-bfbd-f018a80d29d3">bbbb</option>
<option value="28b9089b-7b46-41b7-94b3-d033cb968d32">cccc</option>
<option value="539eeb44-7368-4419-a0f5-fefec2f43de6">dddd</option>
<option value="932de92c-fb0a-46dd-aae7-29427d952d52">eeee</option>
<option value="fd3c3b5a-b241-434f-a9be-2bd6438971a2">ffff</option>
<option value="e88459ab-b2fe-45f4-b07f-e466de7339f3">gggg</option>
    .
    .
    .
    </select>
```

I am trying to get the data out. 
The end result should look like this:

```
    string1 = aaaa
    string2 = bbbb
```

and so on...

Pls help I can't find an answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) html parser for it and also achieve simple through like

```
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(yourhtml);
        Elements options = document.select("select > option");
        int i=1;
        for(Element element : options)
        {
                System.out.println("string"+i+element.text());
                i++;
        }
```

---

**Edit**

Use the direct descendant combinator (>). This combinator expects two selector expressions,
one on either side.if you want to select all option elements that reside directly into select.

Comment: if you want to select all option elements that reside directly into select. you could use this selector called as `direct descendant combinator (>)`

Comment: Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get(); Elements options = doc.select("select > option"); List<String> lsPost = new ArrayList<String>(); for(Element element : options) { lsPost.add(element.text()); } I get an error when I try to use element.text(). Error: Cannot resolve methode 'text()'

Comment: what is import statement for `Element`?